# Resize a non-continuous range to the last cell found on the last non-empty column of that range

Tags: excel, vba

Assume I have a range of non-continuous cells like `"A2:B2,A4:B5,D2,D4:D5,F2:I2,F4:I5"`.
I can get the last empty/non-empty cell of that range by some answers on this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76411819/select-the-last-cell-in-non-continuous-range).
So, I need to resize that non-continuous range to the last cell found on the last non-empty column of that range.
[image]
[image]

```
Sub Make_Selection1()

   Dim sh As Worksheet:  Set sh = ActiveSheet
   
   Dim finalRange As Range
   Set finalRange = sh.Range("A2:B2,A4:B5,D2,D4:D5,F2:I2,F4:I5")
   
   getLastCell(finalRange).Select
      
End Sub

Function getLastCell(rg As Range, Optional fSelectNonEmptyCell As Boolean = True) As Range

    Dim c As Range, a As Range, maxColumn As Long, maxRow As Long
    For Each a In rg.Areas
        For Each c In a.Cells
            If (fSelectNonEmptyCell = True And LenB(c.Value) > 0) Or _
                fSelectNonEmptyCell = False Then
                If c.Column > maxColumn Then maxColumn = c.Column
                If c.Row > maxRow Then maxRow = c.Row
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If maxRow > 0 And maxColumn > 0 Then
        Set getLastCell = rg.Parent.Cells(maxRow, maxColumn)
    Else
        If fSelectNonEmptyCell = True Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 512, , "No non-empty cell found in " & rg.Address(, , , external:=True)
        Else
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 512, , "No cell found in " & rg.Address(, , , external:=True)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

| Title | Title | Title | Title | Title | Title | Title | Title | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |  |  |
| 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |  |  |  |

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is or where you're having trouble? Out of curiosity, what is your use-case for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) With the function you have (`getLastCell`), get the last cell in use within your non-continuous range (`finalRange`) and name if `lastCell`

(2) Build a Range from Cell A1 to `lastCell`

(3) Use the function `Intersect`

```
Sub Make_Selection1()

    Dim sh As Worksheet:  Set sh = ActiveSheet
   
    Dim finalRange As Range
    Set finalRange = sh.Range("A2:B2,A4:B5,D2,D4:D5,F2:I2,F4:I5")
   
    Dim lastcell As Range
    Set lastcell = getLastCell(finalRange)
    Dim tmpRange As Range
    Set tmpRange = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), lastcell)
   
    Dim finalRangeInUse as Range
    Set finalRangeInUse = Application.Intersect(finalRange, tmpRange)

   finalRangeInUse.Select
      
End Sub
```

However, the `Select`-command is only useful when you want to show this cells to the user. If you plan to use it in your code, don't use `Select` (and work on `Selection`). Instead, use the newly created Range variable (`finalRangeInUse`) for further processing.

Comment: I just use `Select` command for illustration result , I tried your code and it is working correctly

Answer (score 2):

### Resize a Non-Contiguous Range

[image]

- The `RefRightMostNonEmptyCell` can be found in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76412832) to OP's previous post.

```vb
Sub Make_Selection1()

    Dim sh As Worksheet:  Set sh = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim finalRange As Range
    Set finalRange = sh.Range("A2:B2,A4:B5,D2,D4:D5,F2:I2,F4:I5")
    
    Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = RefRightMostNonEmptyCell(finalRange)
    
    If lCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No non-empty cells found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim lCol As Long: lCol = lCell.Column
    
    Dim urg As Range, arg As Range, crg As Range
    
    For Each arg In finalRange.Areas
        For Each crg In arg.Columns
            If crg.Column <= lCol Then
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = crg
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, crg)
                End If
            End If
        Next crg
    Next arg
       
    urg.Select
      
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your answer and also works perfectly.

Comment: Note the difference: Ike's `getLastCell` references cell `G5`. the cell at the intersection of the right-most non-empty column and the bottom-most non-empty row of the whole range hence in your case, FunThomas' solution works flawlessly. My `RefRightMostNonEmptyCell` references cell `G4`, the right-most bottom-most non-empty cell hence my answer to this question is more complicated which is the reason I'm posting this (and not to discredit the authors).

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach of getting the range last non-empty column and non-empty row intersection address

```
Function LastCellRange(rangearea As Range) As Range
Dim minrow As Integer, mincol As Integer, maxrow As Integer, maxcol As Integer
Dim ar As Range, arcount As Integer
minrow = Rows.Count
mincol = Columns.Count
maxrow = 2
maxcol = 1
For Each ar In rangearea
arcount = ar.Cells.Count
If ar.Cells(0).Row < minrow And Not IsEmpty(ar.Cells(0)) Then minrow = ar.Cells(0).Row
If ar.Cells(0).Column < mincol And Not IsEmpty(ar.Cells(0)) Then mincol = ar.Cells(0).Column
If ar.Cells(arcount - 1).Row > maxrow And Not IsEmpty(ar.Cells(arcount - 1)) Then maxrow = ar.Cells(arcount - 1).Row
If ar.Cells(arcount - 1).Column > maxcol And Not IsEmpty(ar.Cells(arcount - 1)) Then maxcol = ar.Cells(arcount - 1).Column
Next ar
Set LastCellRange = Range(Cells(minrow, mincol), Cells(maxrow, maxcol))

End Function
```

Additionally this other method find the sheet's last intersection address, but very time consuming

```
Function lastcell(vala As Range) As Range
Dim maxrow As Integer, maxcol As Integer
For i = 2 To Rows.Count
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rows(i), "<>") <> 0 Then maxrow = i
Next i
For j = 1 To Columns.Count
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(Rows.Count, j)), "<>") Then maxcol = j
Next j
Set lastcell = Cells(maxrow, maxcol)
End Function
```